# SAP Ui OData v2 setBindingContext doesn't show data

Tags: odata, sapui5

I'm setting up a table that has a detail view when an Item is clicked. The way I want to implement that is the following:

**Table Controller**
That's the logic to show all my table entries which is loaded from the oData interface.

```
onInit: function() {
    var serviceUrl = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSS18_T4_UNIVERSITY_SRV";
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(serviceUrl);
    this.getView().setModel(oModel);

},

handleLineItemPress : function(evt){
    // Create App object
    var app = new sap.m.App({
        initialPage : this.createId("idDetail1")
    }); 

    // create detail page
    var page = sap.ui.view({
        id : this.createId("idDetail1"),
        viewName: "zss18_t4.projectDetail",
        type : sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML
    }); 

    // Pass Data to detail page
    var context = evt.getSource().getBindingContext(); 
    console.log(context); 
    app.to(page, { ctx : context});


    // Show detail page in app
    app.addPage(page); 
    app.placeAt("content", "only"); 



        }
```

**Detail page**
Now I would like to display a single item's details on a new page, whose controller is here:

```
        onInit: function() {
        var serviceUrl = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSS18_T4_UNIVERSITY_SRV";
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(serviceUrl);
        var view = this.getView();
        this.getView().setModel(oModel);
        this.getView().addDelegate({
            onBeforeShow : function(evt) {
                view.setBindingContext(evt.data.ctx);

            }

        });
    },
```

And this is the corresponding view:

```
<core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
    controllerName="zss18_t4.projectDetail" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form">
<Page title="Details">
<VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
            <f:SimpleForm id="projectDetails" title="Project Details">
            <f:content>
                    <Label text="Project ID" />
                    <Text text="{projid}" />
                    <Label text="Title" />
                    <Text text="{title}" />
                    <Label text="Description" />
                    <Text text="{description}" />
                    <Label text="Type" />
                    <Text text="{type}" />
                    <Label text="Supervisor" />
                    <Text text="{supervisor}" />
                    <Label text="Lead" />
                    <Text text="{lead}" />
                    <Label text="Members" />
                    <Text text="{members}" />
                    <Label text="Status" />
                    <Text text="{status}" />
                    <Label text="Startdate" />
                    <Text text="{startdate}" />
                    <Label text="Enddate" />
                    <Text text="{enddate}" />
                    </f:content>
            </f:SimpleForm>
        </VBox>
</Page>
```

What I'm seeing is this: 
[image]

I've read the similar posts but didn't find the right solution just yet. Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a double check on how the oData Service works and stumbled upon the following blogpost (unfortunately in German): http://fiori.acando-live.de/2018/04/03/odata-model-wie-kommen-die-daten-in-meine-anwendung/ It said that in some cases you have to do a proper oModel.read() to load the acutal data to the frontend, which was missing here. 
I added a **oModel.read()** to retrieve the actual dataset from the backend. The context was correct, but there was no data available.

Here is my implementation for the projects controller, which displays the data correctly:

```
onInit: function() {
    var serviceUrl = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSS18_T4_UNIVERSITY_SRV";
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(serviceUrl);
    oModel.read("/ZSS18_T4_PROJSet")
    var view = this.getView();
    this.getView().setModel(oModel);
    this.getView().addDelegate({
        onBeforeShow : function(evt) {
            view.setBindingContext(evt.data.ctx);

        }

    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local model when you get data from your oData service.

YOu can call your Odata Service like that:

```
var modelTab    =   this.getView().getModel( "localModel" ),
this.getView().getModel( "MyOdataService" ).read( entitySet, {
            filters: [ filter ],
            success: function( oData ) {
                modelTab.setProperty("/", oData.results );
            },
            error: function( oError ) {
            }
        });
```

Like that you can use the model like you want on your xml view

Like that:

```
<Label text="Project ID" />
<Text text="{localModel>/projid}" />
```

Like that you can debug what is the results of your odata request.

Thanks.

Comment: Please use `modelTab.setProperty("/", oData.results)` instead of `setData`

Comment: `setProperty`: _If the model value changed **all interested parties are informed**_

Comment: I wouldn't even suggest to (mis)use ODataModel like this. With JSONModel, you'll have to write and maintain APIs that complies with OData specification (system queries, function imports, batch requests, metadata, annotations, etc). The [ODataModel already supports them](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2). And as we know, models can be set on any ManagedObjects (e.g. View). Make use of it. The framework will handling sending requests appropriately. Yes, there are cases where `read` is unavoidable. Just keep in mind that ODataModel is not just another *"jQuery.ajax"*.